# How to recover password from a user

Tags: password

I have an old blog in wordpress. I can't remember my old password. The last time I acessed, I put the site in maintenance with a plugin.

I have accesse to database and FTP, but I don't know how to recover the password or create a new one.

Website: www.felipestoker.com/encamisetados

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot recover a password, you can only reset it to something new.

We have an article with several ways to do that in the documentation. Pick one of those methods.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password

Comment: This works fine! I did with PHPMyAdmin Acess

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress uses phpass password encryption method. it is basically a one-way hashing algorithm.

If you forgot the admin username you can manually override it using phpmyadmin.

all you need to do is follow this step.

Generate Phpass hash using your password. (check this url http://scriptserver.mainframe8.com/wordpress_password_hasher.php)
Go to the relevant table in the database and change the hashes the one you generated